# How to get object id from Kivy language to Python code

Tags: python, kivy

I created a widget in Kivy language, it has some properties which I'm using some of them inside this widget's python code. Since I'm using "id" keyword inside .kv file, they all have id's. I need to use same ids inside Python code. Here is the workaround:

```
CcaSwitch:
    id: out0_bit3
    name: "out0_bit3"
```

I'm using self.name in place of self.id in python code. How can I achieve same goal without a "duplicate" entry for each widget?

Thanks.

## Edit

I'm using the "name" variable inside Python code like this:

```
class CcaSwitch(BoxLayout):

    name = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.refresh, 5)

    def refresh(self, dt):
        self.comm.publish(get_bool_status(self.name), self.routing_key)
```

So, I need a string, which identifies this widget instance itself, in a DRY way.

I would like to achieve something like that:

In .kv file:

```
CcaSwitch:
    id: out0_bit3
```

In Python I'd like to use it like:

```
 class CcaSwitch(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.name = self.id.__name__
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.refresh, 5)

    def refresh(self, dt):
        self.comm.publish(get_bool_status(self.name), self.routing_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say why you need to use these ids in python. But you can access a widget that has an id through its parent's [ids](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=ids#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids) dictionary (this is a special dictionary that can be queried using dot notation, e.g. if the dict variable is x, and it has element 'apple' in it, you can get its value with x.apple).

So for your example, if you have in .kv:

```
<ExampleWidget>:
    CcaSwitch:
        id: out0_bit3
        state: 'ON'
```

you can .py:

```
w = ExampleWidget()
print(w.ids.out0_bit3.state)
```

w.ids.out0_bit3 in this case returns a reference to that CcaSwitch widget.

**EDIT**

As I said in the comments, there's only one way to get the id value as a string - using its parent's ids dictionary. So the following will only work if the CcaSwitch widget has a parent widget (i.e. it's not the main widget):

```
class CcaSwitch(Widget):

    name = ''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CcaSwitch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.load_name)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.refresh, 5)

    def load_name(self, *l):
        for id_str, widget in self.parent.ids.iteritems():
            if widget.__self__ is self:
                self.name = id_str
                return

    def refresh(self, dt):
        self.comm.publish(get_bool_status(self.name), self.routing_key)
```

What it does, is go through the ids dict of its parent, and extracts its id string. You cannot call self.load_name directly from init, because it might not have the parent yet etc. So we schedule it for the next frame.

If the widget has no parent, you're out of luck and you either have to do like you did before, or if the name doesn't have to be human readable or the same across different runs, you can in init set self.name = str(self).

Comment: I do not create widgets inside python code, they are all created automatically. 

I need to get "out0_bit3" string because this widget automatically sends and receives some data over network using the id. Since I am typing this id for "id: ..." section of the .kv file, I may use same thing for querying while getting data over network.

Comment: Say I use this id in an sql query.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the id as a string, and not the value of the id variable? Maybe show more example code (both how you would like to use it (instead of name) in python and where in kv you use the id) because the ids dictionary in the parent is really the only way you can get the id as a string in python.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that I'm using the id as a string. I edited my first post as you wish.

Comment: I appreciate your help effort, but there is no luck. Last code you have given does not work for me. Although self.parent.children is giving correct children tree, self.parent.ids is an empty list. I have to use my workaround and keep going on. Maybe this is more appropriate since query id (name) for a widget may change in time but there would be a static id which will be used for exchanging data between other widgets. By the way, schedule_once() was a good tip and solved my different problem. Thank you.

Comment: It would be empty if you didn't do e.g. id: out0_bit3. Otherwise it should have all the ids of every child that had an id created (assuming you're using 1.8).

Comment: 1) Yes, I'm using 1.8.

2) I realized that I'm not using id entries anymore if I do not need explicitly. So I ended up creating CcaSwitch widgets without id properties, only with name properties. 

3) I have given my usage in the first post, in the first edit. I have "id: out0_bit3" entry in my CcaSwitch widget. I would love to learn what I did wrong.

Comment: for 3. I'm not sure what you ask. I don't see anything wrong. Do you mean why self.parent.ids was empty? I couldn't tell without full code. But i tested my code using the ids and it worked. If you post your full (or working sample) code with e.g. pastebin I can look at it.

Comment: Hi. I have a similar question - just trying to get the id of the Button that has been clicked on. I can print its text, its pos, etc. but button.id is None. Can I confirm that Kivy does not allow you to simply get the id of a Button that was set in the kv file? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `widget.id` is ever set in kv, so I don't think it can be used.